# ReplyKeyboardMarkup with set python, TeleBot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I've got some set, that I want add to keyboard markup.

```
some_set = {'2', '3', '0.2', '1'}
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
markup.add(some_set)
msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "test", reply_markup=markup)
```

Im getting `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'to_dic'`

So, I was trying to do that in stupid way:
`new_set = some_set[1:-1]` 
So, its turned to:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TjZI.png)
How to do that?

PS: using [telebot](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

Answer (score 0):

**Done** **it!**

```
weights_keybord = set(weights)



   for x in weights_keybord:
        markup.row(x.replace("`", "").replace("\"", "").replace("'", ""))
    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, """test """, reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Method add takes a string as input, not set

Try this:

```
some_set = {'2', '3', '0.2', '1'}
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
for kb in some_set:
    markup.add(kb)
msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "test", reply_markup=markup
```